# SQL insert first of month

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

I've created an initial sql insert into a table, below.

```
spool_month spool_year  spool_month_part  spool_year_part   curr_cnt    prev_cnt    cal_prcnt_dff
July         2020         7               2020                21069199  NULL           0
September    2020         9               2020                18072707  21069199      14
October      2020        10               2020                17284440  18072707       4
November     2020        11               2020                17791289  17284440       3
December     2020        12               2020                20148679  17791289      13
January      2021         1               2021                22543049  20148679      12
February     2021         2               2021                24234982  22543049       8
March        2021         3               2021                26458351  24234982       9
April        2021         4               2021                 5946066  26458351      78
```

Can I create an insert that would only insert new data into this table at the first of the month? So, for example at first of every month insert previous months data.

Not sure where to start with this piece, so any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: Nothing happens natively in sql server based on the simple passage of time. You need to schedule this action in some fashion - how exactly depends on the edition you are using. I suggest you first focus on writing a query that will accomplish your goal whenever it is run. Once that works you can focus on scheduling the task.

Comment: @SMor Thanks. I was thinking I could run the insert daily but on the first of the month it actually inserts the data, else it would not insert.

Comment: Yes, that's what the SQL Server Agent is for. Look into creating a "job".

Comment: You could easily write a procedure that checks to see if current date is the first of month and bails otherwise. Perhaps you want to give it an override parameter for the case where something went wrong and you really do need it to execute on a date not the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily solved by using SqlAgent; if you are only using SqlExpress you won't have access to SqlAgent, in which case you will need to look at using the Windows Task Scheduler and Powershell, if that's the case [here is a useful guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5830/how-to-schedule-sql-scripts-on-sql-server-express-edition/)

Create your procedure that will perform your insert and schedule it to run daily either from a SqlAgent Job or Powershell from link above.

In your procedure, wrap your `insert` with

```
if DatePart(day,GetDate())=1
begin

...

end
```